# Can I use numeric algorithms written in C/C++ efficiently on mobile platforms

Tags: android, c++, ios, algorithm, mobile

We're developing a cross-platform mobile app (iOS+Android) that is to include numerical algorithms, which are somewhat computationally intensive. We are currently in the stage of algorithm development and verification using python on desktop machines. If we rewrite these algorithms in C++ (preferentially, or at least C), will we be able to incorporate them into our app such that they are efficient? If not, is there any other language/library/framework that allows us to port the algorithms once and compile into efficient code for both platforms? Most of the app itself is written in Apache Cordova, but that might eventually change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For Android, use the Android NDK to be able to connect to the C library. In iOS and with Objective-C, you can include and call pure c style functions from `.mm`-files (i.e. objective-C++-files recognised as such by XCode through the `.mm`-extension). For iOS and Swift, you'll need to provide such `.mm`-files as hooks, since swift can call objective-C signatures but not pure c style functions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes. Depending on algorithms you may need to use CPU optimized versions using something like [NEON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Advanced_SIMD_.28NEON.29) inline asm or [intrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) for mobile [ARM CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture), and all of that can be embedded directly into C++ code.

> Can I use numeric algorithms written in C/C++ efficiently on mobile platforms

Making algorithms in NEON is not terribly efficient process, just like writing in assembly, but you may get results that are much faster compared to regular C/C++ code. Depending on algorithms don't forget to check out libraries that might have done that already.

Comment: With efficiency, I actually meant compiling an existing C/C++ algorithm in such a way that raw pointers to standard numeric types stay (instead of e.g. transpiling into some boxing and unboxing operations at each access). Of course, specialised vector instructions are even more performant, and it's good to hear that this is possible!

Comment: @yes, with C++ you can get max speed that CPU can do. Just make sure if you use pointers you make it clear to the compiler that inputs/outputs pointers may alias each other or not. In other words, compiler may skip some obvious optimizations where there is a possibility that some pointers may point to the same data. Usually you can tell to the compiler that there is no aliasing possible with [__restrict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) specifier.